# Getting error while trying to learn more about the company in Stack Overflow jobs portal

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, error-message

I am getting the following error message when I click on

> Learn more about company

link. Here is the screenshot of the error message.
[image]

Comment: I didnt see that similar question had already been asked. I am going to close this question.